# If $P$ is any point on a straight line drawn through the vertex $A$ of an isosceles triangle $ABC$, parallel to the base, prove that $PB+PC>AB+AC$

Tags: triangles

> $C$ and $D$ are two points on the same side of a line $AB$ and $P$ is any point on $AB$. $PC+PD$ is least when the angles $\angle CPA$ and $\angle DPB$ are equal.

I am not able to figure out as to how we can prove this. It would be great if someone could help.

Comment: ...but you've answered your own question!

Comment: but i dont know how to prove the latter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reflect $C$ at the line $AP$ to obtain $C'$. Then $AB+AC=BA+AC'$, where $B,A,C'$ are colinear, whereas $PA+PC=AP+PC'$, where $BPC'$ are *not* collinear. Hence this is just an example of: The straight line from $A$ to $C'$ is the shortest.

Comment: great! just that it would be PB+PC=BP +PC' in 2nd line